# Css columns magic

Tags: css

I have the following layout:

```
b1      b2      b3
c1      c2      c3
```

And would like to insert mr. #monster (argh!) without changing the existing layout, but achieving the following:

```
b1      b2      b3
ARGH            c3
c1      c2
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tt5P8/

The goal is to have a fixed set of css rules, where removing or adding the Monster (ARGH) div will look either figure 1 or 2.

Comment: I don't see that work out with css only. You will need javascript to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/tt5P8/1/

```
#main
{
    width: 300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.box
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.col
{
    float: left;
    width: 85px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#monster
{
    width: 185px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    height: 100px;

}
```

Maybe I am not understanding the question?

Comment: Almost, but c3 has to start right below b3 and/or in the same line with ARGH

Comment: Got ya.  I am with Sven on this one, you would need to use javascript to reorder the DOM elements to your liking on the fly, you can't do this with the way the elements are currently ordered.